# New-MoveRequest -Whatif return type

Tags: exchange, powershell

I am trying to find if there are any issues with a new moverequest. So I am using -WhatIf switch on New-MoveRequest function. I noticed if there are no issues with the moverequest, this function outputs something like `What If: Creating New-MoveRequest for 'John Doe'`. The issue is, I am not able to assign this message to any variable. Where is this message(output) coming from?

```
New-MoveRequest -Remote -Identity $userAddress -RemoteHostName $rhn -RemoteCredential $SourceCredential -WhatIf
```

Comment: Well, with `-Whatif` the cmdlet doesn't actually do anything. What do you expect it to return?

Comment: If there is no -Whatif switch, New-MoveRequest returns MoveRequestStatistics. What does it return with -WhatIf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is that the return type is void. It does not return anything, because the `-WhatIf` switch is meant to not run anything. It only tests to see what the command would do, and writes that information to host.

**Write-Host**

```
$a = Write-Host "Test string"
# Test String will output to console
# $a will be null because the output will go to the console

$a = Write-Host "Test string" | Write-Output "C:\output.txt"
# Test String will output to console
# $a will be null, and output.txt will be empty because the output will go to the console
```

Output from Write-Host is sent explicitly to the console. It will not be able to be stored to a variable or piped to another command, because that is what the standard out stream is for.

**Write-Output**

Write-Output will put information in the pipeline. From there it can be piped into another command. If the output reaches a command that does not have it's output piped somewhere else, it will get stored to a variable if you started the line with a `$var =` statement. If not handled at this point, the output will write to the host console.

```
$a = Write-Output "Test string"
# Console will be empty
# $a will contain Test string

$a = Write-Host "Test string" | Out-File "C:\output.txt"
# Console will be empty
# $a will be null, and output.txt will contain "Test String"
```

Full output stream reference:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you can use `GetType()` to get the type of an object. So just put the result of your command in a variable and use `GetType()` on it:

```
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> $x = New-MoveRequest ... -WhatIf
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> $x.GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:11
+ $x.GetType <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetType:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Result: Using the `-WhatIf` paramater on the cmdlet results in `null`.

To capture all output of the command, including the `WhatIf`-Output you could use `Start-Transcript`:

```
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> Start-Transcript tmpfile
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> New-MoveRequest ... -WhatIf
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> Stop-Transcript
```

This will capture all output and write it into the tmpfile, albeit along with a lot of unintended additional information:

```
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop> Get-Content tmpfile
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20170510090649
Username  : username
Machine   : hostname (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
**********************
Transcript started, output file is x
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop>$x = New-MoveRequest ... -WhatIf
What if: ...
[PS] C:\Users\username\Desktop>Stop-Transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript End
End time: 20170510090701
**********************
```

I haven't found a way to remove all the verbose stuff, so you would have to parse this file again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot troubleshoot the problem using the "-whatif" parameter.  As noted by some commentors, this only validates the command is correct from the standpoint of switches and commands and objects.

For instance New-MoveRequest testusername -TargetDatabase databasename -WhatIf will only give an error if the username doesn't exist or if the database 'databasename' doesn't exist.  Great for making sure you don't have spelling errors.  This will pass a -WhatIf even if there are serious issues with the mailbox that will cause a failure.

If you are having an issue with the an actual move request, please post the error you are getting.

One general troubleshooting note is that if you have a failed move, you can get more details by using Get-MoveRequestStatistics  and look at the following attributes:

- FailureCode
- FailureType
- FailureSide
- Message